# Moving WordPress to subdirectory url: wp-admin throws 404

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm moving my Wordpress blog from a subdomain (where it sits at the moment) to a sudrectory of my root domain. So basically it's now in

```
blog.exampledomain.com
```

And I want it to go to

```
exampledomain.com/blog
```

I can move all the content, but wp-admin throws 404 or redirects in the wrong way. So I'm not able to manage my blog!

The things I've done:

- In the DB: Changed siteurl to exampledomain.com
- In the DB: Change home to exampledomain.com/blog/
- Updated the .htaccess as follows:

  ## BEGIN WordPress

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /blog/
  RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

  ## END WordPress

If I set it like this, the blog itself works but wp-admin throws 404. I also tried an alternative setup of .htaccess I've found around

```
#BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog.
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]

RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

This approach makes it so I'm redirected to

```
exampledomain.com/blog/blog/wp-admin
```

Which again throws 404! I'm stuck now

Additional info not sure if helpful:

- I have an haproxy sending the traffic from the main domain to the Wordpress instance (this is why the files are on the root directory of the WP but I want a subdir URL)
- I will change the static file URLs later from the wp-admin

Answer (score 0):

You have your `siteurl` and `home` the wrong way around.

`siteurl` is where your Wordpress installation is (e.g. `http://exampledomain.com/blog/`).

`home` is where the rest of your website is (e.g. `http://exampledomain.com`).

Changing that should fix it. You can [reset your .htaccess file](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) and save your permalink options again to generate a new correct one (only use the multisite one, if you use multisite).